# pyserial for Python 2.7.2

Tags: python, python-module, pyserial, windows64

*I'm new to Python.* According to the [internets](https://www.google.com/search?q=ImportError%3a%20No%20module%20named%20serial) I was looking for the module [pyserial](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/) after receiving this error:

```
ImportError: No module named serial
```

I first tried to install [pywin32](http://starship.python.net/crew/mhammond/win32/Downloads.html), it went well. But it seems not to contain pyserial. :-(

Then I found a single module installer for pyserial, I was not able to install it, it says it did not found the path to python in the registry. :-(

After that I found [this module](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyserial) on python.org, but I don't know what to do, it does not come with an installer. :-(

How can I add pyserial to Python (64) 2.7 on **Windows 7 64**?

Comment: it's `import serial` in Python 2.7

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could try it with pip. ([Here a question/answer about installing it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-to-install-pip-on-windows))

Then type in your shell:

```
pip install pyserial
```

**Solution:**
The [installation of pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-to-install-pip-on-windows) on Windows 7 64 is a little tricky:
I added my Python and Python/Scripts path to the PATH env.
Then I opened PythonWin as Administrator, ran [ez_setup.py](http://peak.telecommunity.com/dist/ez_setup.py) from http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools#downloads with PythonWin. And then I downloaded [pip](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools) unpacked it and as Administrator I ran `python setup.py install` on the windows shell and after that `pip install pyserial`.

Answer (score 11):

From http://www.instructables.com/id/The-Arduino-Internet-Gizmo/step19/Installing-the-software/

Install pySerial as follows:

Download pySerial from http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyserial - click on pyserial-2.6.tar.gz to download the library.

Run 7-Zip (Start -> All Programs -> 7-Zip -> 7-Zip File Manager).

Open the pyserial-2.6.tar.gz file with 7-Zip (File -> Open).

Double click the "dist" folder.

Single click on the "pyserial-2.6.tar" file and click the "Extract" button at the top of the window.  When asked where to put the file, specify `c:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\pyserial-2.6`

Exit from 7-Zip

Now that you have downloaded pySerial, install it:

Open a command window (Start -> All Programs -> Accessories -> Command Prompt) and type into the command line: `cd c:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\pyserial-2.6`

Install pySerial by typing this command (including the path): `c:\Python27\python.exe setup.py install`

Answer (score 4):

understood that this question is for Windows, but since it comes up first in a Google search let me add an alternative (to pip) for Debian:

`sudo apt-get install python-serial`

Answer (score 4):

As a slight update there is still the problem that python 64bit for Windows is not compatible with the pyserial installer.

What is not mentioned in other answers but I found very useful to know is that **Python 32 bit** installs and works fine on Win7 64bit and that means the pyserial installer also works fine.

Obviously if you need 64bit python this is no use to you, but I suspect most of us do not.

Comment: This was by far the easiest solution I found. Unless you are processing huge datasets, Python 32 bit will work fine for you and the pyserial installer will just work. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

please just go to http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyserial and download the 64 bit installer and that's it!

Answer (score 1):

reviving an old thread but pyserial v3.4 is now available for windows/mac/linux via the conda package manager on the conda-forge channel
(the base conda channel has v2.7)

To install this package with conda run:
`conda install -c conda-forge pyserial`

Answer (score 0):

pyserial comes now with a precomilied(?) Windows .exe installer: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyserial

Answer (score 0):

pySerial can be installed from PyPI:

```
python -m pip install pyserial
```

NOTE : Using the python/python3 executable of the desired version (2.7/3.x).

Answer (score 0):

I find the 2.7 installation files here

https://pypi.org/project/pyserial/2.7/#files

Comment: While helping individuals, we also try to produce a permanent source of future help for others - so answers that produce a tangible record are preferred. Before offering 1:1 help, read [this Meta post](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/280603) and reconsider making the effort to document the answer.