# python 64 and pyserial

Tags: python, pyserial

I am trying to download pyserial and all the installation and everything worked out fine. However, when I try to import it, a traceback is called with the ending error of what pretty much looks like a problem with serialwin32/win32.py

Finding out more, I think it might be a problem with pyserial not working with Python64-bit. Does anybody have any suggestions for this? I can just install Python32 but I wanna know if there is anything I can do to stay with Python64

EDIT:

I was fed up with it so I reinstalled python as python32-bit. but when I try to import serial again, this message shows up in my shell:

```
>>> import serial
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\pyserial-2.7\serial\__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    from serial.serialwin32 import *
  File "c:\pyserial-2.7\serial\serialwin32.py", line 12, in <module>
    from serial import win32
  File "c:\pyserial-2.7\serial\win32.py", line 196
    MAXDWORD = 4294967295L # Variable c_uint
```

Why is this happening please help

EDIT (2):

this was due to change from python 2/3. pyserial is SUPPOSED to work for python 3.x but it apparently doesn't sometimes, so it would be good to run 2to3.py on the pyserial directory and it'll work like a charm. Hopefully.

Comment: Have you checked the following answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8491111/pyserial-for-python-2-7-2 ?

Comment: no, but i found a solution, just about to edit